# Why can't the gas be estimated?

Tags: contract-deployment, gas-estimate, bignumber

I'm trying to use another contract to give my leasingContracts unique IDs, but I can't call the function as the code crashes, and I don't understand why.

This is the contract for IDs:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
enter code here
contract uniqueID {
using Counters for Counters.Counter;
Counters.Counter private _leasingID;

constructor() {
}

function getLeasingID() public returns (uint) {
    _leasingID.increment();
    return _leasingID.current();
}
}
```

This is the leasingContract:

```
const {ethers} = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
const [deployer] = await  ethers.getSigners();
console.log("Deploying contracts with the account:", deployer.address);

const contractABI = [
    {
        inputs: [],
        stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
        type: 'constructor'
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: 'getLeasingID',
        outputs: [
            {
                internalType: 'uint256',
                name: '',
                type: 'uint256'
            }
        ],
        stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
        type: 'function'
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: 'leasingID',
        outputs: [
            {
                internalType: 'uint256',
                name: '',
                type: 'uint256'
            }
        ],
        stateMutability: 'view',
        type: 'function'
    },
]

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/API');
console.log("provider set up");
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet('PRIVATE_KEY', provider)
console.log("Wallet is ready");

const uniqueIDContract = new ethers.Contract(
    '0xF6547Ab8d7Df582498b1EeEE98364aA4DcAb39e8',
    contractABI,
    wallet
);
console.log("Contract loaded");

const leasingID = await uniqueIDContract.getLeasingID();
console.log("leasingID extracted:", leasingID.toString());

const currentGasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice();
console.log("The current gasPrice is:", currentGasPrice.toString());




console.log("Deployment started");
const LeasingContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("LeasingContract");
const contractValueInWei = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.0000000000001");
const leasingcontract = await LeasingContract.deploy(true, leasingID, 123456, 'QmTjhTB8P82B1i7k821Qe4US7vRFWPN12rwoYzVR93bhno', ethers.utils.parseEther(/*"0.44500541"*/ "0.00001"), "0xAC1434008cECfFf845208F295353aaF57C82Bb26", "0x21eecf2729bDDE8Ff7cDCb260171D66B42308b89", "0x21eecf2729bDDE8Ff7cDCb260171D66B42308b89");
console.log("Contract Deployed to Address:", leasingcontract.address);
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

I don't see the problem, but it has the following output:

> Deploying contracts with the account:
> 0x21eecf2729bDDE8Ff7cDCb260171D66B42308b89 provider set up Wallet is
> ready Contract loaded {"reason":"cannot estimate gas; transaction may
> fail or may require manual gas
> limit","code":"UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT","error":{"reason":"cannot
> estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas
> limit","code":"UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT","error":{"reason":"processing
> response
> error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":49,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"gas
> required exceeds allowance
> (0)"}}","error":{"code":-32000},"requestBody":"{"method":"eth_estimateGas","params":[{"type":"0x2","maxFeePerGas":"0x7e440416","maxPriorityFeePerGas":"0x59682f00","from":"0xac1434008cecfff845208f295353aaf57c82bb26","to":"0xf6547ab8d7df582498b1eeee98364aa4dcab39e8","data":"0xb3b54859"}],"id":49,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}","requestMethod":"POST","url":"https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/fiHzC9QihwhH4HyszbeqDtW3pDE27Uf6"},"method":"estimateGas","transaction":{"from":"0xAC1434008cECfFf845208F295353aaF57C82Bb26","maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x59682f00"},"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x7e440416"},"to":"0xF6547Ab8d7Df582498b1EeEE98364aA4DcAb39e8","data":"0xb3b54859","type":2,"accessList":null}},"tx":{"data":"0xb3b54859","to":{},"from":"0xAC1434008cECfFf845208F295353aaF57C82Bb26","type":2,"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x7e440416"},"maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x59682f00"},"nonce":{},"gasLimit":{},"chainId":{}}}